# Expected value problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let the stochastic variable X be evenly distributed over the interval $[0,2π]$ calculate:

1) $E[\cos(X)]$

2) $E[\sin(X)^2]$

How does the integral look?

Does it look like this:

$\int_{0}^{2π}\frac{1}{2π}\cos(\frac{1}{2π})dx$

Comment: Did you check the formula for E(g(X)) when X has PDF f? Or is your problem to find f in the present case?

Comment: You mean $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}\cos(x)dx$?

Comment: @Augustin but X is evenly distributed and has as a probability function $1/2π$ why $cos(x)$

Comment: Actually it's $\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathbf{1}_{[0,2\pi]}(x)$, but check out the formula Did is talking about.

Comment: @Did my problem is that the $cos(X)$ confuses me and I don't know how to think in this situation. Since X is evenly distributed that means that $cos(x) = cos(1/2π)$ for x = [0, 2π]

Comment: @Augustin I have the formula in front of me but it still confuses me

Comment: If you are confused, a more satisfying way to evade your confusion would be to *write down the formula for E(g(X)) when X has density f*. Can you do that?

Comment: @Did $\int_{A}^{ } g(x)*f(x)*dx$ Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Mathguy007 Almost. What is the $A$ standing for?

Comment: @drhab A is the interval which in this case is $[0,2π]$

Comment: If $f$ is defined as in the second comment of @Augustin then you can write the expectation as $\int g(x)f(x)dx$. That is the way you should think about it. A second step: since $f(x)=0$ if $x\notin[0,2\pi]$ and $f(x)=\frac1{2\pi}$ this integral equals $\int_{[0,2\pi]} g(x)\frac1{2\pi}dx$.

Comment: @drhab thank you. For the second case am I write to assume it will be like the same except that $g(x) = sin(x)^2$???

Comment: Yes, that is correct.